# Question on Morse theory

Tags: morse-theory

What is the difference between the theory of Morse study in the book of Milnor: "Morse theory "and that studied in the book" ciritical point theory and Hamiltonian systems "

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is the same theory but in the book " ciritical point theory and Hamiltonian systems " authors show **applications** of Morse theory to Hamiltonian systems. In particular using Morse inequalities you say something about minimal number of critical points on a given manifolds (at least as many as sum of Betti numbers).

For a general paper about Morse theory I highly recommend R.Bott - [Morse theory indomitable](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1988__68__99_0) Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS, 68 (1988), p. 99-114

Comment: so to see Morse theory in Hilber space i must study the Morse inequality ,right ?